# Each time you use present, the memory increase and does not fall. Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I always display different content in the same UI.

But every time you run present, memory grows slightly.
How can I do this without increasing memory?

I tried to share and reuse a single view
If you try fast
`Swift tried to present a modular active controller [Current view controller]`

An error occurs.

```
 func RecommendOpen(){
    if let recommendView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecommendView") as? RecommenViewController{
        recommendView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(recommendView,animated: true)
    }

}
```

Retrieve the new value from `viewDidLoad` in `recommendView`.
recommendView is always the same UI.
Is there a way to reduce memory?

The previously presented `recommendView` will always be closed using `self.dismiss`.

Comment: There must be a strong reference cycle somewhere on the recommendView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My table in recommendView cell's `parentView` was set to `strong var`.
Resolved after `weak var` changing.